# Should I worry about this pipe insulation? (fiberglass vs asbestos)

Tags: insulation, asbestos, fiberglass

I have found those pipes in my basement. I hope its fiberglass, but not sure if its asbestos, because it got placed in the 60's or 70's (in my country the use of asbestos got banned in 2005). These pipes are used for the heating of the house, so they require thermal insulation to be efficient. I know its impossible to determine by a picture, but I hope somebody with a little more knowledge can say what could I do.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: Hungary, Budapest city

Answer (score 1):

Quick test: go outside with a mask and safety glasses, hold at arms length, fiberglass will melt and form tiny beads in a propane torch flame (or perhaps one from a butane lighter), asbestos will glow yellow or white hot without noticeable melting.

Pull a few strands out (while wearing a particle mask) and test them. Normally, I would **not** advise you going into a site with possible asbestos and disturbing it, but you already have entered it, and live there.

Comment: I burned it with a butane lighter, and it melted. I also have a few sheets of glasswool around, burned them too, and I have to say they act the same way.

Comment: Phew! Looks like there's no need to worry. Particles of asbestos could have infiltrated the whole house, so you "dodged that bullet".